# Unable to read from a pipe after something is written to it by a child process

Tags: c, linux, pipe, dup2

I create a function `exec_in_child` which takes the command arguments, pipe file descriptors (`fds`), `read_flag` and `write_flag` as input. When `write_flag` is set to 1, the child process should duplicate `stdout` to `fds[1]`, and then execute the command. When `read_flag` is set to 1, the child should duplicate the `stdin` to `fds[0]` and the execute the command.

- Do I have to close one end of the pipe when I'm reading/writing to
  the other end?
- The code below doesn't work. I'm trying to execute `/bin/ls` inside a child process, write the stdout to the pipe, and then read
  it off in the parent process and print it. I'm not able to read in
  the parent process.
- Can I read and write to the pipe inside the same process without closing other? This situation arises when I want to child to read
  from pipe, execute, and then write to the pipe.

> ```
> #include <stdio.h> /* printf */
> #include <stdlib.h> 
> #include <string.h> /* strlen, strcpy */
>
> int exec_in_child(char *arguments[], const int temp[], int , int);
>
> int main()
> {
>     ssize_t bytes_read;
>     char *curr_dir = (char *)malloc(500);
>     int pipefd[2];
>
>     if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
>         perror("pipe");
>         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
>     }
>
>     char *arguments[] = {"/bin/pwd",0};
>     exec_in_child(arguments, pipefd, 0, 1);
>     bytes_read = read(pipefd[0], curr_dir, strlen(curr_dir));
>     printf("%s = %d\n", "bytes read from pipe" ,(int)bytes_read);
>     printf("%s: %s\n","character read from the pipe",curr_dir);
>     return 0;
> }
>
>
> int exec_in_child(char * arguments[], const int fds[], int read_flag, int write_flag) {
>     pid_t pid;
>     pid = fork();
>     if (pid < 0) {
>         perror("Error: Fork Failed");
>     }
>     else if (pid == 0){ /*inside the child process */
>         if (read_flag == 1) {
>             dup2(fds[0], 0);
>             perror("Dup2 stdin");
>         }
>         if (write_flag == 1) {
>             dup2(fds[1], 1);
>             perror("Dup2 stdout");
>         }
>         execv(arguments[0], arguments);
>         perror("Error in child");
>         exit(1);
>     } /* if (pid == 0) */
>     else {
>         while(pid != wait(0));  
>     } /* if(pid < 0) */
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

I get this result:

```
hmwk1-skk2142(test) > ./a.out 
Dup2 stdout: Success
bytes read from pipe = 0
character read from the pipe:
```

Comment: Don't pass `strlen(curr_dir)` when you want to pass the size of the buffer.  That data is uninitialized, so `strlen` is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks, that was truly a stupid mistake.

Comment: But, to one of your questions, yes you do want to close the other ends of the pipe.  You typically want `dup2(fds[0], 0);` immediately followed by  `close(fds[0]);`, and the parent should close the ends it is not using.  A common source of bugs is that a child process reading from a pipe doesn't terminate because some process (often the child itself) still has one end of the pipe open.

Comment: Got it. In that case, if I want the child to read from pipe (some input to the an executable), execute the executable using execv, and then write the output to the pipe, how can I do that in a way that'd keep only one end of the pipe open at any time?

Comment: Yeah, I think using two pipes would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1) You do not need to close either end of the pipe in order to use the other end. However, you generally want to close any end(s) of the pipe you're not using. The biggest reason to do this is that *the pipe will only close when all open write file descriptors are closed.*

2) Your code isn't working because you're using `strlen()` improperly. This function calculates the length of a string by searching for the null (0) character. When you `malloc()` the storage for `curr_dir` you have no guarantee of what resides there (though it will usually be zeroed, as in this case).

Thus, your call `strlen(curr_dir)` returns zero, and the `read()` system call thinks you want to read up to zero bytes of data. Change your read call to the following:

```
bytes_read = read(pipefd[0], curr_dir, 500);
```

and your code will work perfectly.

3) You can read and write to any pipe you've got a valid file descriptor to. A single process can absolutely read and write the same pipe.